# Excel vba On Error GoTo different handlers, depending on an error

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel vba code that opens different files on makes use of them. An error can occur because there is no file where excel loos for it. I want to create a `MsgBox` on such errors with a message which specific file is absent.

Now I can only

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

ErrorHandler:
     MsgBox("File is absent")
```

But I can't specify which exactly file is absent. Is there a way to achieve it through error handler? Maybe through some additional variable?

**EDIT**: I open files through

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=...
```

But I'm curious about what one should do if the case is

```
Dim fileTitle As String
filetitle=Dir()
```

as well.

Comment: What code are you using to open the file(s)? Is it the Dir() statement? If so, s=Dir() returns the name of the file if found, and an empty string if not. It all depends on how you are looping through the files.  Please supply your code

Comment: What you *should* be doing is ensuring the file exists before your program attempts to open it, and then routing appropriately (i.e., to an `Exit Sub` with a message box that informs the user that some required inputs for the program are not available). Don't spaghetti your code with error-handlers for things which you can reasonably anticipate, instead, build appropriate logic in to your code to avoid the unhandled exception which raises the error, and exit cleanly.

Comment: I would just use FileSystemObject to check if the file exist before you attempt to open it

Comment: @Zac `DIR` function is much faster than using FSO :)

Comment: @DavidZemens yes I agree. From what I know, you do get more functionality with FSO. But for this scenario, you are correct.. `DIR` is a better option :)

Comment: @Zac FSO is also more beginner friendly, IMO, because it's an object you can view in the VBE debugger/etc, not some magical function that isn't visually exposed to the VBE.

Comment: @DavidZemens good shout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding the file path via:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=...
```

Use a variable to represent the file path/name:

```
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "C:/path/to/my/file.xlsx"
```

Then, check to make sure it exists before you attempt to open it:

```
If FileIsAccessible(fileName) Then
    ' Do stuff
Else
    MsgBox fileName & " doesn't exist or cannot be opened"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Use a custom function like

```
Function FileIsAccessible(path$) As Boolean
    Dim FF As Long
    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    FF = FreeFile

    'Does file exist?
    '  Raises Error 53 if file not found
    Open path For Input Access Read As FF
    Close FF

    'If file exist, is it accessible?
    '  Raises error 70 if file is locked/in-use
    FF = FreeFile
    Open path For Binary Access Write As FF
    Close FF

EarlyExit:
FileIsAccessible = (Err.Number = 0)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll use your method. Is it too much to ask how to use `FileSystemObject` you talked of in comments? Your custom function looks hard to me.

Comment: Yes, it is too much to ask. There's ample documentation you can use to work with FileSystemObject :)  If you have trouble with that, ask separate question specifically about the FSO. Also, this custom function should be much easier to implement, it is something you can literally copy & paste in to your code and call it as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You still have access to your variables in error handler, so you know within which file error happen:

```
Sub ...
    Dim filename As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    filename = Dir(...)
    While filename>""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename)
        ...
        filename=Dir
    Wend
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & " File: " & filename
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to go about this.  First, as you suggested, (which is also the easier of the two), you can make a variable that will carry the file name that you reassign after each file successfully loads.  That name can then be passed into your message box in the event of a failure.  If all you need to do is pass this name, this is the better solution.

The second option would be to create multiple error handlers.  I would only recommend this if you need more customization with regard to how the error is handled, like wanting a different message to be displayed based on which type of file was missing.  This option would make your code a good bit messier (as you would need to reassign the `On Error GoTo ...` statement multiple times, but its worth considering if you need a more complex solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm curious about how the second solution would look like, couldn't find that customized error handling syntax.

Comment: @Ans it would be quite ugly.  You'd basically need to have multiple error handlers (e.g. `ErrorHandler1`, `ErrorHandler2`, etc) and then reassign the `On Error GoTo` statement each time you need to use a different one

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and tweak it as per your requirement. This will give you a starting point to deal with error handling....

Assuming you are trying to open a file abc.xlsx which is located at your Desktop and if this file isn't found on Desktop, the error handling will be triggered.

Don't forget to use Exit Sub before Error Handling label so that it is not executed if the file was found.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String

FilePath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\abc.xlsx"

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
'Other stuff here if file was found and opened successfully
'
'
'
'
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
     MsgBox Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbCritical, "File Not Found!"
```